Keycloak throws NPE when replacing client_session_host in back-channel-logout url
we're using the keycloak placeholder ${application.session.host} in the back-channel-logout url to allow the clients to configure their host dynamically in case a back-channel-logout request needs to be sent to them. In oder that to work, the clients have to send in their token request the required parameters client_session_state & client_session_host and then the whole magic happens in the background by keycloak to resolve the host in the back-channel-logout url automatically by this client_session_host.
We can see in the logs from keycloak that the client_session_host was sent successfully from the client:

Adapter Session '1234' saved in ClientSession for client 'client1'. Host is 'client1.host.com'

However, when the back-channel-logout should happen is applied for client1, keycloak throws an NPE that the host of client1 is null. The exception happened when replacing the client session host  placeholder with the host coming from the client session host, this is the code line in keycloak :
String currentHostMgmtUrl = backchannelLogoutUrl.replace(CLIENT_SESSION_HOST_PROPERTY, host); https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/managers/ResourceAdminManager.java#L182
The host in this case was read from the client_session_host and strangely it's null. I could not figure out really why. Did anyone have the same problem and how to fix it? Could it be a problem that the client is running with multiple pods in kubernetes and somehow the client_session_host was not correctly reached to keycloak?
Also about the client it's a webflux based application and to send the two required parameters client_session_state & client_session_host it defines a custom ReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient bean which adds the two parameters:
@Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> authorizationCodeAccessTokenResponseClient() {
        WebClientReactiveAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
            new WebClientReactiveAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        accessTokenResponseClient.addParametersConverter(authorizationGrantRequest -> {
            MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            params.set("client_session_state", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            params.set("client_session_host", "client1.host.com");
            return params;
        });
        return accessTokenResponseClient;
    }

I did try to do some searching for documentations but still no success
